# Is a method an object in Java?

Tags: java, object, methods

Is a method an object in Java?

I had that doubt and wondered if anything useful could be done if the answer was yes.

I googled but I didn't find anything useful. Thanks.

Comment: That's what the Reflection API is all about. Read about `java.lang.reflect.Method`

Comment: @Tunaki It's not that a method is an object. An instance of `Method` is not the method itself, it's just an object that allows you to access that method.

Answer (score 2):

> Is a method an object in Java?

Methods are not first class objects in Java.

You can use reflection and this provides a object of type `Method` which allows you to call the method, but this is not the actual method in the PermGen or Metaspace.

Answer (score 0):

No, methods are not objects in Java.